# How to periodically update the dependencies in a production Python environment?

Tags: python, pip

I am responsible for maintaining a Python environment that is frequently deployed into production. To ensure that the library's dependencies work well together, I use pip to install all the required Python packages, following best practices I `pip freeze` all of my dependencies into a `requirements.txt` file.

The benefit of this approach is that I have a very stable environment that is unlikely to break due to a package issue. However, the drawback is that my environment is static while these packages are constantly releasing new versions that could improve performance and most importantly fix vulnerabilities.

I am wondering what the industry standard is for keeping packages up to date in an easy way, perhaps even in an automated way that detects new updates and tests for any potential issues. For instance, apt has a simple `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` command to keep your packages constantly updated and be aware of it.

The obvious answer is to just update all packages to the latest official version. My concern is that this can potentially break some dependencies between packages and cause the environment to break.

Can anyone suggest a similar solution for keeping Python packages up to date while ensuring stability?

Comment: Is the situation that the software won't change and so there won't be any chances of updating the dependencies in a development process? Also consider that not every update is beneficial, some don't fix any issue, just add functionality or fix problems your program doesn't encounter

Comment: In reality software is always changing since any average deployment depends on at least 20 packages. Updates are important because they fix holes in your system's security.

Comment: Well, if it's constantly changing consider deploying your program and its dependencies a package, you would update them in development and do a fresh install everytime you deploy (that is a model followed by React applications, for example, where dependencies are not considered environment but part of the application). To best manage dependencies in an environment with multiple applications I suggest using conda, docker and the like

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can't say what the industry standard is but one of the ways I could think of to update the packages periodically would be as such:

1. Create a `requirements.txt` file that contains the packages to update.
2. Create a python script that contains bash commands to update the packages in the `requirements.txt`.
3. Can use `pip freeze` to update the `requirements.txt`
4. Create a cron job or use the python `schedule` library to trigger a periodic update

You can refer, as an example for

- cron job on mac, to: https://www.jcchouinard.com/python-automation-with-cron-on-mac/
- schedule in python, to: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-schedule-library/

The above can solve the update issue but may not solve the compatibility issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To my understanding this is a pain-point that Python packaging hasn't solved yet. All of the solutions I can think of are quite "hacky" and then as you said the compatibility issue is another beast. This is not a small problem because it is a decent security flaw.

Answer (score 2):

The importance is not so much current but to not have vulnerabilities that may harm customers and your company in any way.

Industristandard is to use Snyk, Safety, Deptrack, Sonatype Lifecycle etc to monitor package/module vulnerabilities. And a Continuous-Integration(CI) system that support this like docker containers in kubernetes.

Deploy the exact version you are running in prod and run vulnerability scans.
(All CI systems make this easy)
(it is important to do on running code because the requirements.txt most likely never show all installed that will be installed)

The vulnerability-scanners (all except owast deptrack) costs money if you like to be current, but they in its simplest form just give you a more refined answer to:

- https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=python

You can make your own system based on the safety source
https://github.com/pyupio/safety and the CVE list above and make it fail if any of the versions are found in your code.

When it comes to `requirements.txt` listings we always use `>=` in favor of `==` and deploy every night in test-systems and run test-on them, if they fail we manually have to go though errors and check and pin the releases.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you build [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) images or similar.  (There are other VM solutions, but Docker seems to be the most common/popular.) Have `apt-get update`, `apt-get install` and `pip install -r requirements.txt` as part of the Dockerfile, and integrate it into your [CI/CD pipeline](https://docs.docker.com/language/java/configure-ci-cd/) using [GitHub or similar](https://stackshare.io/github-actions/alternatives)

That builds the image from scratch using a well-defined process.  You then run the VM, including [all automated unit and integration tests](https://www.ranorex.com/blog/types-automated-testing/) and flag any problems for the Devs.  It's then their job to figure out whether they broke something, whether they need a particular version of some dependency, etc.

Once the automated tests pass, the image binary (including its "frozen" dependencies) gets pushed to a place where humans can interact with it and look for anything weird. Typically there are several such [environments](https://www.pagerduty.com/resources/learn/what-is-ci-cd-environment/) variously called things like ["test", "integration", and "production"](https://walmyrlimaesilv.medium.com/development-test-performance-staging-canary-production-environments-a26c03509fa8).  The names, numbers, and details vary from place to place - but that triplet is fairly common. They're typically defined as a sequence and gating between them is done manually.  This might be a typical spec:

1. Development - This is the first environment where code gets pushed after the automated testing passes. Failures and weird idiosyncrasies are common.  If local developers need to replicate a problem or experiment with a patch that can't be handled on their local machines, they put the code here. Images graduate from Development when the basic manual and automated "smoke tests" all pass and the Dev team agrees the code is stable.
2. Integration - This environment belongs to QA and dedicated software testers. They may have their own set of scripts to run, which may be automated, manual or ad hoc. This is also a good environment for load testing, or for internal red team attacks on the security, or for testing / exploration by internal trusted users who are willing to risk the occasional crash in order to exercise the newest up-and-coming features. QA flags any problems or oddities and sends issues back to the devs. Images graduate from Integration when QA agrees the code is production-quality.
3. Production - This environment is running somewhat older code since everything has to go through Dev & QA before reaching it, but it's likely to be quite robust. The binary images here are the only ones that are accessible to the outside world, and the only ones carefully monitored by the [SOC](https://www.comptia.org/content/articles/what-is-a-security-operations-center).

Since VM images are only compiled *once*, just prior to sending the code to Dev, all three environments should have the same issues.  The problem then becomes getting code through the environments in sequence and doing all the necessary checks in each before the security patches become too outdated... or before the customers get tired of waiting for the new features / bug-fixes.

There are a lot of details in the process, and many questions & answers on StackOverflow's [sister site for networking administration](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/continuous-integration)